# Apache Camel message exchange does not wait for the response

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have following code for publishing message to activeMQ and reading response via exchange. But code seem to be returning instantaneously and not waiting for the response. Could you please point what is wrong with the following Scala code.

```
def sendAndReceiveExtractionDetails(request:String, header: String) : String = {
    val exchange: DefaultExchange = new DefaultExchange(camel, ExchangePattern.InOut)
    exchange.getIn.setBody(request)
    exchange.getIn.setHeader("meshId", header)
    producer.send("activemq:queue:extractor-jobs?requestTimeout=1400000", exchange)
    val out: apache.camel.Message = exchange.getOut()
    out.getBody().toString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
  def sendAndReceiveExtractionDetails(request:String, header: String) : String = {
    camel.createProducerTemplate()
      .sendBody("activemq:queue:extractor-jobs?requestTimeout=1400000", ExchangePattern.InOut, request).toString
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to ignore the `ExchangePattern` you set. Have you tried to set it on your JMS URI as `activemq:queue:...&exchangePattern=InOut`?

I am not sure if you also need to define the `JMSReplyTo` header on the message or if this is done automatically when the exchangePattern is InOut.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request` method on the producer as that is for `InOut`